# How do I edit and delete items?

Tags: html, typescript, angular

I'm trying to build my own client - server application. I've set up a simple html skeleton and used some of the methods from the exercises to add items to the server. No database stuff so far tho. I got this method for adding items, from the service class:

```
 addItem(name:string, price:number, successCallback, errorCallback) {
      this.http.post('/item', JSON.stringify({name: name, price: price}), {headers: this.headers}).subscribe((response) => {
        this.items.push(new Item(+response.text(), name, price));
        successCallback();
      }, (response) => {
        errorCallback();
      });
    }
```

The next logical step would be deleting / editing items, but the example did not cover this, and all though it's probably fairly simple i can't figure it out or find another example that fits. I was hoping someone here could help me out. it's mainly the http stuff i struggle with.. i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement the following methods for this:

```
updateItem(id:string, obj:any) {
  this.http.put(`/item/${id}`, JSON.stringify(obj), {
    headers: this.headers
  }).subscribe((response) => {
    var itemIndexToUpdate = this.items.find((item => item.id===id));
    this.items[itemIndexToUpdate] = obj;
  }, (response) => {
    (...)
  });
}

deleteItem(id:string) {
  this.http.delete(`/item/${id}`, {
    headers: this.headers
  }).subscribe((response) => {
    var itemIndexToRemove = this.items.findIndex((item => item.id===id));
    if (itemIndexToRemove != -1) {
      this.items.splice(itemIndexToRemove, 1);
    }
  }, (response) => {
    (...)
  });
}
```

Otherwise I wouldn't leverage callbacks into the `addItem` method but leverage rather observables.

Answer (score 0):

try these -

```
EditRequest(url,data) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))

        this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Put,
            url: url,
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res) {
                    return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
                }
            });
    }

 DeleteRequest(url,data) {
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
    this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))

    this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Delete,
        url: url,
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
                return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
            }
        });
}
```

and than subscribe these where you want as per need.